# Is there an online tile-based elevation service?

Tags: web-service, dem, tiles, elevation

I am working on an application that requires the elevation at a given lat/long coordinate for lots of closely spaced coordinates along any given irregular path. (The path is a trace of a glider/hang-glider flight.)

I could use SRTM/GTOPO30/GLOBE data but I only need small (but arbitrary) sections of the world at any one time so I'd like to avoid storing a DEM database locally.

There is also Google's elevation API (for use with their maps) but it has a usage limit of 2500 requests a day whereas my data can be tens of thousands of points. Plus querying a server so many times for closely spaced locations seems like a waste a bandwidth.

So, ideally, I'd like a tile server for small DEM tiles. I found this http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1b48cd3b6276416784fe90a68c580a89 but the ArcGIS API guide doesn't contain any useful info about it. Has anyone actually used it? Are there any other similar services?

Comment: You may find this previous StackOverflow discussion useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090534/how-to-look-up-elevation-data-by-lat-lng/3171904#3171904

Answer (score 5):

Another api that you can query instead of google's is the US Geological Survey Elevation Query. Information about their service can be found here:

gisdata.usgs.gov/XMLWebServices/TNM_Elevation_Service.php

A request looks like this:

http://gisdata.usgs.gov/xmlwebservices2/elevation_service.asmx/getElevation?X_Value=-118.4&Y_Value=36.7&Elevation_Units=METERS&Source_Layer=-1&Elevation_Only=true.

Comment: As of December 2015, that URL throws a 500 error. Looks like it's gone.

Answer (score 3):

Esri has [an Elevation SOE](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/apl/archive/2010/10/07/Elevation-Server-Object-Extension.aspx) that can be [accessed via REST](http://sampleserver4.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Elevation/ESRI_Elevation_World/MapServer/exts/ElevationsSOE/ElevationLayers/1/GetElevations).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be down at the moment, but I think http://www.heywhatsthat.com/ might provide that service, and if he doesn't he might open to the idea. Cache of the [FAQ page here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_OV2Vp7GcRQJ:www.heywhatsthat.com/faq.html+http://www.heywhatsthat.com/&hl=en&client=firefox-a&gl=ca&strip=1).

[image]

Comment: The source code of the profile page points to a very interesting javastring script, which could be customized I think (not trivial, but feasible).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, MapQuest Open Elevation Service can help http://open.mapquestapi.com/elevation/

I don't find informations about a query limitation after a quick search about this.

Answer (score 2):

MapZen has data on their website and AWS S3 that's great. 
 THey have many formats. I like the Terrarium PNG format 
You have to decode the RGB Values using this formula.
(red * 256 + green + blue / 256) - 32768
You can use MapBox Raster Tile Query https://github.com/mapbox/raster-tile-query or another library to read the RGB values out of the RGB.  I've displayed them in Leaflet and OpenLayers nicely and even color coded the elevation values.
Here's a link
https://mapzen.com/documentation/terrain-tiles/use-service/
You can access the data without API key from the AWS S3 Bucket. 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/terrarium/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/normal/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/{z}/{x}/{y}.tif
https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/skadi/{N|S}{y}/{N|S}{y}{E|W}{x}.hgt.gz

Comment: The nice thing about this is that you can download the data make an mbtiles or geopackage and have it offline

Answer (score 0):

you can see here:
elevations soe 10.1 Esri http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=60bf17f2d59441839135adc25654a7d9
or 
my soe 10.1 if you need also other methods of ISurface (LoS, Locate, Countour ect) 
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1c96538fa81948efb5a2436532964def

Answer (score 0):

Mapzen has [some tile sets](https://mapzen.com/blog/elevation/), including a nice elevation viewer [here](https://tangrams.github.io/heightmapper/) (info [here](https://mapzen.com/blog/tangram-heightmapper)), which shows grayscale elevation tiles with dynamically locally-adjusted contrast.