# Changed aws terrain datasets

Tags: terrain, amazon-web-services, mapzen

I noticed that the structure and size of the file was changed

- pattern https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/{z}/{x}/{y}.tif
- example https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/1/1/1.tif

Old files described here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/252936/97778

But now (on 11-12 November 2017) I get 512x512 tiles with no tiling.

These files were previously located at

- pattern https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/v2/geotiff/{z}/{x}/{y}.tif
- example https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/v2/geotiff/1/1/1.tif

Who can tell me. Is there correct place to get terrain tiles?
Or some notification channel about new changes

Answer (score 1):

I have found that this is working.

For example: [https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/10/200/354.tif](http://'https://s3.amazonaws.com/elevation-tiles-prod/geotiff/10/200/354.tif') should download a .tif.

As far as .tif files go, I know that Mapzen's wonderful tile service is no longer working. Also, what was supposed to give continuity to the service (Nextzen's) .tif service doesn't appear to work, though .png and terrarium-style images do (try https://tile.nextzen.org/tilezen/terrain/v1/256/normal/10/196/353.png?api_key=yourkey) You can go to their site to get your own api key (replace 'yourkey' above).

I have a python project with an AwsDem class that will download a series of tiles and resample and reproject them according to a rasterio-style profile (https://github.com/dgketchum/dem)